# Printing SOAP messages for a JAVA CONSOLE CLIENT

Tags: java, logging, soap, log4j, soap-client

I am developing a java console client using a third party web service. After I point to their WSDL, I am able to get their code and send SOAP request and response. I want to log those transactions in a log file. Any idea on how to log a SOAP message at the client side.

Thanks in advance,
Praveen G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webservice Stacks provide convenient out and in interceptors for intercepting outgoing requests and incoming responses both on the client and server side. You should be able to use this feature to log outgoing requests from your client and incoming responses, here is a sample using [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-LoggingMessages) and using [Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#d4e1413)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying it out :)